# Reverse a known algorithm in Python using no third party libraries

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, cryptography, transformation

I've got a method that hashes an array of integers, shown below:

```
def digestm(message):
    digest = []
    for i in xrange(0,len(message),1):
        digest.append(0)
        if i != 0:
            digest[i] = ( (129 * message[i]) ^ message[i-1]) % 256
        else:
            digest[i] = ( (129 * message[i]) ^ 0) % 256
    return digest
```

I want to reverse this algorithm.

Example:

```
>>>message = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
>>>digestm(message)
[0, 129, 3, 129, 7, 129, 3, 129, 15, 129, 3, 129, 7, 129, 3, 129]
```

I want to know how to convert the returned array back into the message array.

Thus far, this is the code I have come up with, but it is definitely not right:

```
def answer(digest):
    message=[]
    for i in xrange(0,len(digest)-1,1):
        message.append(0)
        if i!= 0:
            message[i] = ((digest[i] ^ digest[i-1])*129)%256
        else:
            message[i] = ((digest[i] ^ 0)*129)%256
    return message
```

Comment: hashes typically only work one way

Comment: @ArtomB the modulo makes it lossy ... I guarantee that for any solution you come up with I can give you an input it will not reverse

Comment: Is that really a hash algorithm, because your output has the same length as your input... it's just kind of transformation.

Comment: ^ That's a good point. Hash functions usually have a mapping domains {0,1}^* -> {0,1}^n, but this one has {0,1}^n -> {0,1}^n. Since it is reversible, it also cannot be said to be a hash function.

Comment: @ArtjomB. It's no hash function and it cannot fully reverted due to the modulo `%`. If this would work N = NP, whatever...

Comment: @l3li3l Are the input values limited to `[0; 255]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
message[i] = ((digest[i] ^ digest[i-1])*129)%256
```

to

```
message[i] = ((digest[i] ^ message[i-1])*129)%256
```

Since during `digestm` you're XORing the current and the previous plaintext blocks, you have to XOR with the plaintext block and not with the ciphertext block during `answer`.

Also, you need to remove the `-1` in `for i in xrange(0,len(digest)-1,1):`

This is a pretty bad hash function. Take for example `b = 129 * a % 256`:

```
a => b
0 => 0
1 => 129
2 => 2
3 => 131
4 => 4
5 => 133
...
129 => 1
130 => 130
131 => 2
...
```

You get the idea. It is perfectly reversible, because it has this property.

Comment: Why try to correct a broken hash function? Use hashlibs, CRC-algorithms, whatever... you can be sure there is enough entropy in it.

Comment: You should ask that the OP.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Where is this assumption written?

Comment: @wenzul It doesn't that's why it's an assumption or even an educated guess based on `% 256`.

Comment: @wenzul Also, you probably know that practically all cryptographic functions (such as a hash function) operate on bytes. There is no reason to expect something different. I agree that OP shouldn't have used the term "hash function", but you didn't take the time to see what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

A [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is a one-way lossy function. You cannot reverse it. The loss takes place due to the modulo `%` operator. You will lose the quotient (if you will use values greater than 255).

In your case it's just a substitution of values in the same range via a function.

Comment: that said you might be able to generate rainbow tables to find *an* input that gives that output ...

Comment: So, could I populate a list of all possible answers and just test them until it comes up with the right answer?

Comment: @l3li3l Sure you can do that in this direction and it will work well if the input possibilities are just a few. You should also avoid to write your own hash function because it's defecitve and collision susceptible.

Comment: If the data set were small you could do that, but in general this problem is not decidable.